# Align text vertically in a span

Tags: css

I want **"text 2"** to be aligned vertically center to a text before it (i.e. **"text 1"** here).

### HTML code:

```
<span style='font-size:22px'>text 1</span><span class='two'>text 2</span>
```

### CSS code:

```
.two{
    color:red;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I thought `vertical-align:middle` for the `.two` class but it doesn't seem to work..

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBh4e/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to apply `vertical-align` to both `<span>`.

```
span { vertical-align: middle }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BBh4e/2/

Answer (score 3):

Create a container for your text content, a span perhaps, and do the following:

```
span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: @JoshC: Yes, I agree. But just one thing to note is that when the font-size is less (say 20px for the first) the vertical-align wouldn't look too obvious. (Atleast in Opera it doesn't). I think adding a `line-height` to the spans in addition to the already suggested would be better.